# new lines in big query strings

Tags: google-bigquery

What exactly does "new-lines in strings" mean?

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy#import

How to check and remove it?

```
Import Jobs: Daily limit: 1,000 import jobs per table per day (including failures), 10,000 import jobs per project per day (including failures)
Maximum size per import job: 1TB uncompressed
Maximum number of files per import job: 500
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

newlines in strings refers to embedded newline characters within CSV field values. this makes it difficult to parallelize imports.

e.g.: 2 lines, the first has an embedded newline:

```
1,2,"this is my
string",4,5
1,2,"another string",4,5
```

The BigQuery importer has the "--noallow_quoted_newlines" option, which signifies the file doesn't contain any embedded newlines.

```
# --noallow_quoted_newlines:
#   Do not allow quoted newlines in the data.  This allows BigQuery to parallelize the load.
```

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/ingestioncookbook#atomic

> Individual JSON and CSV files without newlines in string fields may be as large as 100GB, and CSV files that contain newlines within strings must be 4GB or less.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/ingestioncookbook

Comment: Specifically, CSV with newlines are much more difficult to processes in parallel. Recent BigQuery import changes will read large input files in parallel in order to process them more quickly.

Comment: Seems all links to Bigquery docs are now broken? searching for 'newline' on the page of the first link returns no results